# How can I use drupal_static() to save an element in an associative array?

Tags: 7

I'm making repeated calls to a few related object instances, and I need to cache them in memory.

If I have an array of objects, like:

```
array('object_a' => $obj_a, 'object_b' => $obj_b);
```

I want to do something like:

```
$obj_a = getmyobj('object_a');
```

Where the object is created if it doesn't exist in memory already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [drupal_static](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7.x) to store an array of object.

You can then define a method, lets call it 'getmyobj', to get your data like this :

```
function getmyobj($obj_name) {
  $objects = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__);

  if (! isset ($objects[$obj_name])) {
    // Here you load your obejct
    $objects[$obj_name] = method_to_load_your_object($obj_name);
  }
  return $objects[$obj_name];
}
```

Then you will be able to get you object with the above code :

```
$obj_a = getmyobj('object_a');
```